# Insert values from two dropdownlists into a column in the database, but one at the time

Tags: asp.net-mvc

At the moment I'm trying to insert a value from two dropdown lists. The users aren't allowed to select both dropdown lists at the same time. One at a time.

I have tried different options now, so now I will show you what I have.

The user can select a value from two dropdown lists, when they have selected the radio button they want.

[image]

**View**

In this view, the user can select a value from one of the two dropdown lists.

```
<div id="Man">
    @Html.DropDownList("SeriesID_Man", null, "Vælg  serie / årgang", new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlMan", string.Empty })
</div>
<div id="Women" style="display:none;">
    @Html.DropDownList("SeriesID_Women", null, "Vælg  serie / årgang", new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlWomen", string.Empty })
</div>
```

**Controller**

In the HttpPost ActionResult method I try to save the selected values

```
[Route("opret-spiller")]
public ActionResult CreatePlayer()
{
    ViewBag.ClubListID = new SelectList(db.ClubLists, "ClubListID", "ClubName");
    ViewBag.PositionID = new SelectList(db.Positions, "PositionID", "PositionName", "PositionCategory", 0);

    ViewBag.SeriesID_Man = new SelectList(db.Seriess.Where(x => x.GenderID == 0), "SeriesID", "SeriesName", "SeriesCategory", 0);
    ViewBag.SeriesID_Women = new SelectList(db.Seriess.Where(x => x.GenderID == 1), "SeriesID", "SeriesName", "SeriesCategory", 0);

    return View();
}

[Route("opret-spiller")]
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePlayer(PlayerProfileViewModel viewModel, Player player)
{
    ViewBag.ClubListID = new SelectList(db.ClubLists, "ClubListID", "ClubName", player.ClubListID).SelectedValue;
    ViewBag.PositionID = new SelectList(db.Positions, "PositionID", "PositionName", "PositionCategory", player.PositionID).SelectedValue;

    ViewBag.SeriesID_Man = new SelectList(db.Seriess.Where(x => x.GenderID == 0), "SeriesID", "SeriesName", "SeriesCategory", 0).SelectedValue;
    ViewBag.SeriesID_Women = new SelectList(db.Seriess.Where(x => x.GenderID == 1), "SeriesID", "SeriesName", "SeriesCategory", 0).SelectedValue;

    Session["viewModel"] = viewModel;
    Session["player"] = player;

    return RedirectToAction("ChoosePlayerAbonnement");
}
```

**Model**

In my model class have I created two fields, that is not mapped to the database, the idea here was to save one of the selected values, from the dropdown lists in the view.

```
[NotMapped]
public int? SeriesID_Man { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public int? SeriesID_Women { get; set; }
```

**Repossitory**

In the repo, I try to insert the value from SeriesID_Man, and SeriesID_Women into database.

```
SeriesID_Man = player.SeriesID,
SeriesID_Women = player.SeriesID,
```

Comment: In which case Women div will be active?

Comment: if the user select the radio button, then the application run some javascript

Comment: Not related to your question.... But I would suggest using strongly typed views and only use ViewBag and Session in special cases.